# Question on prepositional constructions

Tags: infinitive-constructions

Consider the below sentences.

> We do not have much time in which to do it.
>
> There is the item with which to do the task.

I think these constructions are called infinitival relative clauses, a combination of infinitival clauses and relative clauses. In infinitival clauses, it is possible to introduce a subject by means of 'for': *This is a task **for you** to do*, etc.

Is it possible to do the same in these constructions? In other words, is the sentence *There's not much time in which for you to do it* grammatical. If not, why not?

Comment: "There's not much time in which for you to do it" may be textbook right and still awful.  "There's not much time for you to do it" may say what you want to say.

Comment: No, you can't use a relative pronoun with a relative infinitive unless it's pied-piped. _That's the wrench with which to hit it_ is OK because _with_ is pied-piped instead of stranded at the end. If it is stranded, the _which_ has to go: _That's the wrench to hit it with_ but not *_That's the wrench which to hit it with_. Also bad: *_That's the bread which to buy._ You can't pied-pipe a direct object.